# Which is Best tool to develop an android application for Kit Kat?

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

I am planning to start with an android application . I earlier used eclipse .{lease suggest any other tool which is bit comfortable in terms of UI .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eclipse is best platform for Android platform . Google Android studio is not a stable release.
You can still use Android studio as it works well with minor bugs which are unnoticeable

Answer (score 0):

You should know that the ADT Plug-in for Eclipse has its own set of annoying problems...like suddenly disappearing from the menus and not allowing re-installation.  I went through that a few times and decided to give Studio a try.  Nothing against Eclipse, just the plug-in from Google.

Now that Android Studio is in beta, I would recommend it over Eclipse unless you are doing native code development, which Studio does not yet support.  In Beta, things are deprecated instead of just abruptly changed.  So updating as new Studio versions come out should not be too painful.